# jqgrid date picker problem

Tags: jqgrid

For a couple of days now I have been playing around with the jqgrid.I have been trying to accomplish what is found on this example http://www.the-di-lab.com/demo/apples that is placing a date picker on the modal form.

So far I have tried to follow what I found on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246329/jqgrid-date-picked-within-add-edit-window/1303037#1303037) but I get a `target.getAttribute is not a function` error in my ui.datepicker.js script.

Anyone who has done it succesfully?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you or someone else is still seeking for an answer.
I just realized this by using the editoptions in column definition, like so:

```
 ... ,editoptions:{dataInit:datepicker}
```

where datepicker is a function like

```
 function datepicker (elem) {
  jQuery(elem).datepicker(
      // {} // options here
  );
 };
```