# Open Datepicker situated inside of Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trouble with jQuery Dialog and Datepicker plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715677/trouble-with-jquery-dialog-and-datepicker-plugins)

At the moment I have the dialog defined as :

```
  $('#dialogCl').dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     width:650,
     height:550
  });
```

And the datepicker defined inside `#dialogCl` as :

```
 $("#c").datepicker({showOn: 'button', buttonImage: 'images/calendar.gif', buttonImageOnly: true});
```

I need to open the datepicker but it seems it puts the datepicker under the dialog.

I found some posts here regarding that but i didnt knew where how to set the z-index of the `.ui-datepicker` to `1003` programaticly

Answer (score 1):

Dialog has a zIndex option that you can use

```
  $('#dialogCl').dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     width:650,
     height:550,
     zIndex: 800
  });
```

Comment: Fortunatelly your code works just perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - my solution was to add a z-index to jquery-ui*.css for **.ui-datepicker**.

You could try something like `$('.ui-datepicker').css({'z-index': 1003})` if you don't have access (or don't want to modify) your css file.

Answer (score 0):

My best answer is to set the datepicker UI above all dialog layers :)

```
.ui-datepicker
{
  z-index : 9999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the datepicker should either place itself on top of everything visible since it's a flyout, or it should accept a zIndex parameter like the dialog does.

Are either of these the case? So far the css hack shown here `($('.ui-datepicker').css({'z-index': 1003}) )` is the only one that's worked.

Thanks!