# datepicker JQuery function in modal window

Tags: jquery, window, datepicker, modal-dialog

I'm trying to add datepicker in my modal window, but I had no success so far.

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#date_start").datepicker({ showOn: 'button', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: '/images/pick_date.png' });
});
</script>

<div><?php echo $this->form->date_start ?></div> //this form element has id="date_start"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what does "no success" mean? What did you get? And, what does "modal window" mean? Did you mean modal dialog? Did you remember to include jquery-ui javascript file?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of the following: [rouble-with-jquery-dialog-and-datepicker-plugins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715677/trouble-with-jquery-dialog-and-datepicker-plugins)

Comment: "no success" mean absolutely nothing happens.
Modal dialog, you're right.
Yes, I included jquery-ui javascript file

Comment: nothing, it's like datepicker doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> nothing, it's like datepicker doesn't exist

Then probably your code runs before the DOM is ready. Fix things so it runs after the DOM is ready. jQuery can help you do this.