# Using jQuery .dialog() and .datepicker() with z-index

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-datepicker

Trying to load `.datepicker()` inside a `.dialog()`

I'm doing this, but it doesn't seem to come up at all in the dialog:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ui-datepicker-div").css("z-index","9999 !important");

    // tried this too
    $(".ui-datepicker").css("z-index","9999 !important");
 });
```

FireBug says it's still `<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" style="position: absolute; top: 339.4px; left: 656.4px; z-index: 2; display: block;">` when loaded.

Whats wrong here? I looked at this with no help: [Trouble with jQuery Dialog and Datepicker plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715677/trouble-with-jquery-dialog-and-datepicker-plugins)

Comment: Are the datepicker and dialog divs positioned?  z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)

Comment: the object is already `absolute` see update above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

console log `$('#ui-datepicker-div').length` it's possible it's not in the dom at the point that's run.

If that returns 0, then you'll need to move that code appropriately to after it exists in the dom.