# Jquery datepicker is not working on jquery dialog with dynamic contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, datepicker

I have two jsp pages one main.jsp and other is dialog.jsp, in main.jsp i call the java script function *openPopup(url, title)* to open the dialog and load the content of dialog from given *url*.
**Here is my code.**
**main.jsp**

```
<div id="dialogDiv"></div>
<div>
     <a onclick='openPopup("/WEB-INF/views/template/dialog.jsp", "Add Address")' title="add value"></a>
</div>
```

**dialog.jsp**

```
   <div class="loaddiv">
       <form:form method="POST" commandName="address" id="dialogForm">        
          <form:input id="livingSince" path="livingSince" cssClass="datepicker"/>
       </form:form>
   </div>
```

**common.js**

```
$(function(){    
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    showAnim: 'fold'
});     

});

//for pop up
function openPopup(url, title) { 
$("#dialogDiv").load(url + " .loaddiv").dialog({
    position: 'center',
    modal: true,
    resizable: true,
    bgiframe: true,
    autoOpen: true,
    //height: 450,
    width: 500,
    title: title,
    buttons: {
        Save: function () {
            $("#dialogForm").submit();
            $("#dialogDiv").dialog('close');
        //$("#dialogDiv").html('');
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $("#dialogDiv").dialog('close');
        }
    }
   });    
}
```

Now my problem is datepicker is not showing on the dialog after clicking in the input text field. Even though it is perfectly working on the simple jsp page, but not on the dialog (popup).

I also try this solution but its not happening for me.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490819/jquery-dialog-and-datepicker-plugins-dont-work-together)

Comment: is the datepicker js file included in dialog.jsp?

Comment: yes its included and its working fine on simple jsp page

Answer (score 0):

I am loading dynamic content as well. I am using time pickers though instead of date pickers. I was very frustrated that the time pickers would not work if I loaded the content (with time pickers) dynamically.

I solved the problem though by calling a method each time the modal was loaded. Inside this method I load the dynamic content; and then (again) I re-register the time picker. I have attached an image of my code that shows how this is done. It is working perfectly now.

[image]